# How to decompress a very large zipped file (.zip ~10 GBs)?

Tags: python, csv, zlib, unzip

How to decompress a very large zipped file (.zip ~10 GBs) using a python library? This is a 50 GBs compressed CSV file. I used the following code:

```py
import zipfile
import zlib
import os

src = open(r"..\data.zip", "rb")

zf = zipfile.ZipFile( src )

for m in  zf.infolist():
    # Examine the header
    print ("Info ::",m.filename, m.header_offset)
    src.seek( m.header_offset )
    src.read( 30 ) # Good to use struct to unpack this.
    nm= src.read( len(m.filename) )
    if len(m.extra) > 0: ex= src.read( len(m.extra) )
    if len(m.comment) > 0: cm= src.read( len(m.comment) )
    # Build a decompression object
    decomp= zlib.decompressobj(-15)
    # This can be done with a loop reading blocks
    out= open( m.filename, "wb+" )
    print("Out ::",out )
    result= decomp.decompress(src.read( m.compress_size ), )
    out.write( result )
    result = decomp.flush()
    out.write( result )
    # end of the loop
    out.close()
zf.close()
src.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Info :: data.csv 0 **2853497750** b'\x01\x00\x08\x009\xd7\xb3T\x05\x00\x00\x00' b''
Out :: <_io.BufferedRandom name='Sample_big.csv'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 5>()
     16 out= open( m.filename, "wb+" )
     17 print("Out ::",out )
---> 18 result= decomp.decompress(src.read( m.compress_size ), )
     19 out.write( result )
     20 result = decomp.flush()

error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type**
```

I need to transform the zipped file to hdf5 in order to manipulate the data using the vaex library.

Comment: honest question: why unzip it? CSV is only readable linearly, anyway (least useful data format for 10GB of data, still it seems to be commonly used for large data sets... sigh. People tell me you can read a CSV file with a text editor, but I have yet to meet a single person able to gain any kind of overview from a 10 GB sized text file. This discussion is really at least 35 years old), and ZIP can be linearly uncompressed on the fly easily. It's faster to read a compressed file and unzip it on the fly than to read the uncompressed, much larger data from storage!

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: What do you want to do with this file? [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can read zipped CSV files for example. You can open a stream on the CSV with [ZipFile.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open)

Comment: Basically the same way you'd decompress any zip file in python. What's your specific problem? Where's your code?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the benefit of CSVs is that you can *append* to them without having to parse the existing data. For the same reason it's very easy to partition them for parallel processing, eg using map/reduce.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's a very weak benefit. *Most* other mass data file format can be appended to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos even more important: **No**, CSV is **not** easy to partition, at all! The opposite is the case. CSV is a worst-case data format for splitting. To know where to split, you need to read and parse *all the lines* up to the point where you want to split. If you need to figure out how many lines there are, you need to parse all the file. That's often computationally more heavy than the computation you want to do!

Comment: Not weak at all. Which is why json-per-line is used to store events in JSON form in IoT and high volume event based systems. Simple text appending requires *no* preprocessing or indexing

Comment: OK, you found a less useful data format for mass data, @PanagiotisKanavos. Who in their right mind would put data that they could also arrange tabularly, as necessary when representable as CSV, in JSON?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, CSV is very easy to partition. If you split at position 100000 and find it's not a newline, you only need to forward until the next newline. This way, if you want to split in 10, you only need 10 seeks and up to a line's length or reading *10. After that, the mappers can simply read the stream from their start to their end position

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we might have very different views on what constitutes *correctness* of partitioning. If "yeah, I probably end up splitting the file in 10 roughly equally sized partitions. I don't care that for a large files, the error in partitions is normally distributed with standard deviation proportional to total number of lines." is good enough for you, OK. For me, that's not a partitioning, sorry.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I do map/reduce, it's because complexity is high, and compute time needs to be spent efficiently. Since you almost certainly (stochastically speaking) not hit a fair partitioning this way, you're making sure that 9 out of 10 shards wait for the one job that got the larger partition. That's just... bad. Like, if your job is data science, you should not do this, or you didn't actually need to partition in the first place.

Comment: @MarcusMüller not bad, because the difference is at most a single line. More importantly, formats like these can be streamed, which is why they're used in *very* high performance event processing systems like Azure Event Hub and IoT systems. AWS, Azure, Google, Spark, all support this. Especially for IoT, this is a very cheap format to produce and emit

Comment: (let's ignore the fact that in your seek model, you're assuming a specific constraint about quoted strings in your CSV, namely, that they must not contain line breaks. You might be able to know that, in general, CSV is very weakly defined, and some CSV dialects are, some variants are not correctly parseable without *context*. If you're in the latter case, then your seek-and-hope-for-a-line-break method can't work.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller you can complain to AWS, Azure, Google et al and explain to them why they got it wrong. Especially for event processing. Yes I know about CSV issues. I also know how high-throughput systems work. Big data isn't always static

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's **not** at most a single line. That's plain incorrect. Assume you have a million rows, the first half of which are simply a character shorter (e.g. because a time counter crossed a power of 10). Then seeking to 1/10 of the file doesn't give you 10⁵ +- 1 line, but *a lot more* lines, because they are systematically shorter. This is a very common problem.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos AWS, Azure, GCP etc not being interested in doing things most efficiently if they can enable more (read: less well-trained) data workers to rent their compute time is not a strong argument for CSV, is it, especially if the resulting job runs just a justifiable percentage longer than strictly necessary. (and: 10 GB of textually representable data is already "big data"… huh. I must be in the wrong business :) )

Comment: Python's `zipfile` module handles the compression and decompression for you, so it's unclear why you are trying to do it manually yourself — just extract the single member that's in the .zip file you have.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in you attempting (and failing) to interpret and act on the details of the zip file data structures, not to mention creating and writing to subdirectories specified therein, when the whole point of Python's `ZipFile` is to handle that all for you.

If you want to extract the contents, just use `zf.extractall()`. If you want to extract just one entry, use `zf.extract(`*one entry from the infolist*`)`. If you want to read the entry like a file, use `f = zf.open(`*one entry from the infolist*`)`, and `f.read(`*some amount*`)`.

Comment: Have you worked with large zipped csv's or is this just a suggestion! i've done it before and it doesn't work!!!

Comment: Yes, it works. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I used the following versions of python : 3.9, 3.9.7, 3.9.12 ! ! but the py7zr library works for me.

Comment: If you can help me, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

''' python '''
import os
destination = "Sample"

if not os.path.exists(destination):
os.makedirs(destination)

os.system(f"unzip Sample.zip -d {destination}")

The library py7zr works in these types of problem. Here after the solution using the py7zr.

```
''' python '''

import py7zr
with py7zr.SevenZipFile("file.7z", 'r') as archive:
     archive.extract(path=r"...\tempfolder")
```

Comment: Add that to the question. Don't post an answer to add new information

Comment: Then it's not a zip file. It's a 7z file.

Comment: it is a file (.zip), but I can't solve the problem using the zipfile library, so I tried another approach

Answer (score -1):

The right answer is this:

```
import os
destination = "Sample"

if not os.path.exists(destination):
      os.makedirs(destination)

os.system(f"unzip Sample.zip -d {destination}")
```

Comment: Please edit your already existing answer.